# Android: Geocoder always returns my current address when I pass different locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm trying to fetch the address of the user selected location from the Google maps. For fetching the address I'm using GeoCoder.

```
        geoCoder.getFromLocation(location)
```

Always returns my current location address, even when the location changes.

Note: I'm calling this method onLocationChange()

**Updated:**

But for the same location, when I send location from GoogleMaps.OnLongClickListener it works fine. It doesn't work only on LocationListener.onLocationChanged.

Comment: I will suggest you to use google's Place API for getting the address of any location.

Answer (score 0):

use below method to get address of a geo location -

```
public static String reverseGeoCoder(Context mContext,double lat,double longi){
    try{
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        List<Address> matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
        Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));
        String address = bestMatch.getAddressLine(0)+" "+bestMatch.getAddressLine(1);
        return address;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. The problem could be with how you are using your LocationListener.

```
LocationManger lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, new LocationListener() {
    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
            result.append(address.getCountryName());
        }
     }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    }
    }
```